# Passing Form Values to PHP Search

Tags: php, html, search

So I am trying to build a basic search engine, using PHP and HTML

*Right Now I have the API side of it working by manually putting in values, into the query*

But I want to **create a form so the user can enter there own values**

I have the form made, I just cant figure out how to pass the values in the API call

Any help would be great

All revelant code is below

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>PhpFiddle Initial Code</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head>

<body>
<form method="get">
Search Value 1: <input type="text" name="Input Value 1""><br>
Search Value 2: <input type="text" name="Input Value 2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php

    $parameters = array(
        'api_key'   =>  "API_KEY_HERE"
        , 'query'   =>  array('Input Value 1' => 'Input Value 2')
    );


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here below is a fully tested and working solution for your problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Basic Search Engine</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--
        Created By: Dean Van Greunen.
             Email: deanvg9000@gmail.com

        Form Attributes (Basic)
        - Action : This refers to where the data will go once the form is submited,
                   You may use a URL action="https://www.example.com/search"
                   a local URL such as action="/search"
                   or it may be left blank for the page to send the data back to itself. action=""

        - Method : this is how the data will be sent, you have 2 options
                   GET - This will send the form variables in the url and can be accessed via $_GET variable
                   POST - This will send it in the data block, which can be accessed via $_POST variable

    -->
    <form action="" method="POST">
        Search Value 1: <input type="text" name="search[]"><br>
        Search Value 2: <input type="text" name="search[]"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
        //checks if anything has being posted to this page through a POST request.
        //on a normal page load a GET request is sent
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            //checks if any data is in the search variable
            if(!empty($_POST["search"])){
                //loops through all data and prints it
                for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST["search"]); $i++) { 
                    //checks if that search value in the array is empty or not
                    if(!empty($_POST["search"][$i])){
                        echo "Search ".($i+1)." is: ".$_POST["search"][$i]."<br>";
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //the above just reprints the search so you know that it is work, a proof.
        if(!empty($_POST)){
          if(!empty($_POST["search"])){
                $parameters = array(
                    "api_key" => "API_KEY_HERE",
                    "query"   => $_POST["search"] //here am putting the request array of searches into the query.
                );
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So my friend here you have some context, it is dynamic as well, if you ever wish to make a 100 search boxes

Comment: i'm using POST in this as its better for sending data than GET due to the limitations that the GET has regarding data size that it can handle.

Answer (score 0):

For your form
Set the inputs to the following

```
<input type="text" name="search[]"/>
```

Use that for each search field you would like to use.

Modify your forms action to a url and or leave it blank for it to load on the same page.

Add the method attribute to the form field and set it to "post"

In the php section you can send your parameters from reading the $_POST["search"] it will return as an array so have fun and enjoy.

I'm currently on my phone. Will type something up for you if you don't quite understand in a bit.

Comment: Some more context would be great, when you have the time

Comment: @ClarkPamler93 Please see my new answer post with detailed information, if you need any help feel free to email me, or tag me in any comments.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly - you want users to be able to enter search terms via a form?

First off build your form properly - you currently have `action` set wrong, I believe that should be method.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
 Search Value 1: <input type="text" name="input_1" placeholder="Enter your first search term"><br>
 Search Value 2: <input type="text" name="input_2" placeholder="Enter yuor second search term"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now your form makes sense, so once the user presses the submit button, the values they entered in the form will be available in the POST request. Submitting the form will just refresh the page because `action=""`

Now you want to retrieve these values by doing

```
  $searchTermOne = ""; //initailze the variables
  $searchTermTwo = "":
 if($_ISSET['input_1']){ //check if the value was set, it should be if the form was submitted
    $searchTermOne = $_POST['input_1']; //assign the value to the variable
 }
 if($_ISSET['input_2']){
    $searchTermTwo = $_POST['input_2'];
 }
```

Then you can set them in your query paramaters

```
$parameters = array(
    'api_key'   =>  "API_KEY_HERE",
     'query'   =>  array('Input1' => $searchTermOne, 'Input2' => $searchTermTwo)
);
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should be pretty close!

Let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: Yeah so the user enters in 2 values into the search field and clicks submit those 2 values are then passed into the corresponding php, also I have update my form with the correct method not action

Comment: @ClarkPamler93 Sorry I submitted the answer by accident, see the full version now